# Simple C If Statement

Tags: c

I made a very simple C program that is supposed to count how many characters and words are in a string (I count words by checking how many spaces are in the text and one to it). The current code is the following (with no 'printf's to keep it shorter):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int character;
    int words, characters = 0;
    while ((character = getchar()) != '\n') {
        characters = ++characters;
        if ((character == ' ') || (character == '\d')) {
            words = ++words;
        } 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that counting words do not work. I get an accurate count for characters, but words always gives me 2293576, and I cannot for the world figure out why.

Can someone solve this mystery for me?

Thank you for all your answers; I really appreciate the help.

and sorry if my primitive skills made some of your heads hurt. I am a beginner but hopefully improve fast.

Comment: `i = ++i` makes my brain hurt..

Comment: I recommend learning how to use the debugger. You could have caught the problem right away upon stepping past the initialization and noticing that `words` isn't `0`!

Comment: What they mean to say is, `++words` is sufficient.

Comment: +1 (offsetting) Not understanding the downvotes. While OP may not demonstrate years of proficiency in C, the question represents his best effort to work through the roadblock he's encountered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't initialized `words`. Uninitialized local variables in C default to an undefined value and are not automatically initialized to zero.

The statement

```
int x, y = 0;
```

Is not the same as

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
```

Comment: I love how C never does this... Lots of other languages do.

Comment: I've learned to appreciate that C does this... favoring compact code over programmer-friendliness sometimes. Mind you, it's an acquired taste.

Comment: Darn, so simple... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BobKaufman How so? I don't see how it would be practical in any way to have it. So it's kind of just convenience.

Comment: @sinni800: It's nice because it doesn't get done if you don't need it. For example, say you are going to pass the variable to a function to get initialized. Having the variable initialized before you call the function is just wasted cycles. Modern languages are moving away from this type of approach in favor of more fool-proof ones. But C has always been about efficiency.

Comment: @sinni800 it allows C to allocate memory for something on the stack, but it doesn't have to assign any value into it - its just giving you access to something that was freed earlier. Small performance increase for most things, but maybe larger increase for a big struct allocation.

Comment: @sinni800 - I've written code for embedded systems where every byte and every clock cycle counts. (Think 4k RAM and a 1MHz clock) not wasting clock cycles on unnecessary initialization can make a difference.

Comment: It makes sense that it doesn't default. I would hate to do division with an uninitialized variable.

Comment: I see. I didn't think about that. I never coded for anything embedded and had enough Gigahertz at my disposal to not have to care about this in addition to that I never tried to code anything that has no time to waste any cycles.

Answer (score 3):

You don't initialize words to 0. Also, change this:

```
characters = ++characters;
```

to just:

```
characters++;
```

(and for `words` too).

Also, what is the `'\d'` character (besides a plain old d)?

Answer (score 2):

You fail to initialize "words". In the statement:

```
int words, characters = 0;
```

`characters` is assigned to 0, but `words` is left unintialized so it could contain any integer value. The rest of your code then modifies `words` in its unintialized state. Instead of starting at 0 and counting up, `words` is starting at something like 2293576 and counting up from there. To fix your code assign `words` to 0 as well as `characters` before using them in the for loop.

```
int words = 0, characters = 0;
```